# How to scroll to another component on the current page oncick

Tags: reactjs

So I need to move the screen to another component on the page when a link is clicked. I know it involves using refs but I'm not sure how to implement.

My footer component is as follows:
**Footer**

```
class Footer extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
}
scrollToMyRef = () => window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current.offsetTop);
render() {
    return (
            ...
            <div className="footer-bottom">
                <div className="container-row">
                    <div className="footer-col footer-logo">
                        <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="footer-col">
                        <h2>INFORMATION</h2>
                        <a href="/blog">Blog</a>
                        <a ref={this.myRef}>Review</a>
                        ....
```

I got this from the react docs on refs, I'm unsure where I'm supposed to point to the component I want to reference, or if I can just scroll to a point on the screen using window.scroll to (that would be fine too.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is using HTML-anchor by <a href="some-id">From</a> and <div id="#some-id">To</div> not enough for your purposes?

Comment: You only to use `refs` is you need to access the DOM element and manipulate it some how, like add or toggle a CSS class for example. @Alexandr just gave you the answer to solve you problem.